# Finding church records for the Kuck family in Grudziądz, Bydgoszcz, Poland?

Tags: 19th-century, poland, church-records

Gottlieb Kuck was born in 1879 in Grudziądz, Russian Poland. Gottlieb married Dorothea Hefner 1903, and had children Frieda Katherine born 1905, Reinhold was born 1907.

I am looking for Lutheran birth & marriage records for surname "Kuck" from this area 1874 - 1910, especially for these individuals.

I have checked Family Search, ancestry.com, and many others such as  SGGEE, www.luteranie.pl, Evangelische Kirchenbücher, Evangelical records in Poland's State Archives, all Evangelical Augsburg etc.

Are there any other online resources that may have this data?

Comment: Hi jkatherinekuck, and welcome to GenealogySE. I've made some minor edits to your question, I hope I haven't changed your meaning. If you want to add more information or change anything back, click the [edit] link.

Answer (score 6):

You have the wrong administrative description of Grudziądz in 1879, which is possibly contributing to your difficulty in finding records. Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grudzi%C4%85dz), "Following the First Partition of Poland in 1772, the city was annexed by the German Kingdom of Prussia. ...Until 1920 Graudenz belonged to the administrative district of Regierungsbezirk Marienwerder in the Province of West Prussia."

You said you searched at FamilySearch -- but not everything they have is digitized and not everything is indexed. For example, search the [FamilySearch catalogue](https://familysearch.org/catalog/search) using the placename "Graudenz," and you will find a number of microfilms and books. In particular, [Kirchenbuch, 1622-1919](https://familysearch.org/search/catalog/278606?availability=Family%20History%20Library), Authors: Evangelische Kirche Graudenz (StKr. Graudenz), Parish register of baptisms, marriages and deaths for Graudenz, West Prussia, Germany, now Grudziądz, Bydgoszcz, Poland, fits your request. (The film notes say that the originals were filmed in archives in Berlin-Dahlem, Berlin-Charlottenburg and Warsaw).

Comment: re: the 1879 place description, that was partly my fault. The place name was given differently in the title and content, and I tried to make it more consistent - obviously a mistake. I'll change it back to how it was.

Comment: The points I was highlighting with regard to the placename is that in 1879 the proper name of the city was Graudenz, and that it was in West Prussia, Germany -- not Poland nor Russian Poland.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to join the forum at [Genealodzy.PL](http://genealodzy.pl/PNphpBB2.phtml) which has a section for questions in English. On the site, they are also building a database of birth, marriage and death records at the [site](http://www.geneszukacz.genealodzy.pl/) although I suspect that they are mostly from Catholic parishes.